# Coveralls badge is displaying as 'unknown'

Tags: java, spring-boot, jenkins, gradle, coveralls

I have developed a springboot application with Gradle. I have integrated Jenkins and now I'm trying to integrate code coverage into my project. I was using JaCoCo coveralls with Jenkins CI for the purpose.

**Gradle plugin**

```
plugins {
   id 'com.github.kt3k.coveralls' version '2.10.1'
}

jacocoTestReport {
  reports {
    xml.enabled = true
    html.enabled = true
  }
  getClassDirectories().setFrom(classDirectories.files.collect {
        fileTree(dir: it,
                exclude: [
                '**/BmsService*',
                '**/BmsClientWrapper*'])
  })
}
```

And my Jenkins job invokes the following JaCoCo test command.

```
sh "gradle clean test jacocoTestReport coveralls"
```

My Jenkins build gets successful and the data is being sent to *https://coveralls.io* successfully.

**My question is:** if I do a build with **feature branch (except master)**, in coveralls.io the badge was not displayed properly and even it doesn't show the 'committed by' as well. I'm using GitHub by the way.

[image]

[image]

Any help would be grateful!

**Following are the pipeline jobs I have:**

```
stage('Git checkout') { 
           deleteDir()
           checkout(scm)
        }

        stage('Build Source code') {

           container('gradle-docker') {
              sh 'gradle -version'
              sh 'gradle clean'
              sh "gradle build"
           }
        }

        stage('Code Coverage') {
            if('master'.equals(env.BRANCH_NAME)) {
                def secrets = [
                    [$class: 'VaultSecret', path: 'secret/build/credentials', secretValues: [
                        [$class: 'VaultSecretValue', envVar: 'COVERALLS_REPO_TOKEN', vaultKey: 'coveralls_repo_token']
                    ]]
                ]
                wrap([$class: 'VaultBuildWrapper', vaultSecrets: secrets]) {
                    container('gradle-docker') {
                        sh "gradle clean test jacocoTestReport coveralls"
                    }
                }
            } else {
                println 'Code Coverage is only for the master branch, Skipping for ' + env.BRANCH_NAME
            }
        }
```

Comment: are you trying to achieve something like this? https://www.tomasvotruba.com/blog/2017/06/12/how-to-require-minimal-code-coverage-for-github-pull-requests-with-coveralls/

Comment: Yes @DavidHlavati, but I'm trying it with Jenkins not Travis. When trying that only I have got the above mentioned issue.

Comment: I was planning to implement it in the close future, when I get some time for it on a php - jenkins combo, so if you get the answer by then I'll check it out, otherwise if I'll solve it before and there is no answer yet, I'll come back and let you know about the process.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [coveralls documentation](https://docs.coveralls.io/supported-ci-services#insert-your-ci-here) you need to configure CI_BRANCH environment details.

And even it's mentioned in [coveralls gradle plugin](https://github.com/kt3k/coveralls-gradle-plugin#ci-services).
You need to extract this information using `git` commands and populate the required variables.

Comment: Yes I have tried adding some of the environment variables (ex: CI_NAME, CI_BRANCH, GIT_BRANCH) but didn't work though. By the way these variables are actually not required for the plugin if we are using Travis CI, CircleCI, Jenkins CI or Bitrise CI, which will be automatically detected. In my case, I'm using Jenkins.

Comment: Can you print these variables in Jenkins logs and see whether these variables are detected or not?

Comment: Yes I did that with `echo sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'env')` in jenkinsfile and the variables are showing properly.

Comment: I have updated my question with the pipeline jobs I have in my Jenkins file. Hope that helps!